# How to migrate from Tapestry 4 to 5?

Tags: java, spring, tapestry

I have an legacy application written with Taspestry 4.

How can I upgrade it from Tapestry 4 to Tapestry 5.3.8?

Unfortunately I have never had experience before with Tapestry.

I can't find any migration guide. All what I can find on Internet is

> Tapestry 5 did not even attempt to be backwards compatible to Tapestry
>   4. Instead, it laid the ground work for true backwards compatibility going forwards.

Currently I just found that annotations:

```
import org.apache.tapestry.annotations.InjectObject;
import org.apache.tapestry.annotations.Persist;
```

may be replaced with

```
import org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.annotations.Inject;
import org.apache.tapestry5.annotations.Persist;
```

Also how can I get rid off `hivemodule.xml`?

I'll be thankful for any links, documentation or advice.

Comment: Hi @Sergey, did you by any chance document the changes made while upgrading Tapestry?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no simple migration possible. From the [tapestry website](https://tapestry.apache.org/general-questions.html#GeneralQuestions-HowdoIupgradefromTapestry4toTapestry5?):

> There is no existing tool that supports upgrading from Tapestry 4 to
>   Tapestry 5; Tapestry 5 is a complete rewrite.

You might be possible to upgrade/rewrite your application incrementally by building some session sharing services. Disclaimer: I have never attempted this nor have I seen it done between tapestry 4 and 5. I have seen it done with a migration from tapestry 5 to wicket. So see it in that light, if you wish to move away from tapestry 4, you'll have to rewrite partially/completely. Which raises the question what it is you need to achieve that can't be done with tapestry 4 and focus on how to best achieve that.

I know it is probably not the answer you were hoping for. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I found this website addresses that issue. [tapestry site](https://tapestry.apache.org/configuration.html)

Look at the Segregating Applications into Folders section near the bottom of the page. Tapestry 5 allows itself to be stashed in a folder, allowing the user to slowly transition their project from the old format (i.e. Tapestry 4) into Tapestry 5. Best of luck!